# Google+ API - issue getting posts on business page

Tags: java, google-plus

So I am using java API to get public posts from a google+ business page.

```
` String businessPageId = "104451189002914239318"; `
`List<Activity> activities = plus.activities().list(businessPageId, "public").execute().getItems();  // no activities returned `
```

Even though there are public posts, the above call does not return any posts.

I did discover that , getting the Person for that page as

```
`String personId = plus.people().get(businessPageId).execute().getId();`
```

and using `personId` instead of `businessPageId` gets the posts.

What does the above call represent.? is it the page owner.?

Can anyone shed light what's going on here.?

Comment: Can you clarify where the "userId" in your example comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's two pages that have been merged together. If you visit https://plus.google.com/104451189002914239318 you will see it redirect to https://plus.google.com/108277438040092360159. Use the second ID and you should be all set.

Comment: I ended up doing the same. The question I had is what 'merging' mean.? Is on the user that created the page and the other a page Id .?

Comment: My guess is there was a Google+ Page ID and a Google Place ID there were merged into using a single ID.